# Cardano Rosetta API returning 5000 error occurred - Cannot read property 'key_deposit' of undefined

Tags: cardano-db-sync

Cardano Rosetta Construction endpoints /construction/preprocess and other endpoints are returning 5000 Error with Cannot read property 'key_deposit' of undefined". Also, /construction/metadata is returning  Cannot read property 'min_fee_a' of undefined". This is for rosetta 1.8.0 with db-sybc 13.0.0

Answer (score 1):

This error is happening as the epoch_param table is empty and the APIs need Protocol parameters for the epoch. The table is left empty if we use the --disable-ledger parameter while running the db-sync. More here, https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-db-sync/blob/master/doc/configuration.md#--disable-ledger

For a quick fix, enter value in the protocol parameters in the epoch_param table.

Warning: Running db-sync with this flag and then restarting it without the flag will cause crashes and should be avoided.